# Run sql script using batch file from command prompt

Tags: mysql, sql, batch-file, cmd

```
D:
cd Tools/MySQL5/bin
mysql -u root mysql
use xyz;
source C:/Users/abc/Desktop/xyz.sql;
\q
```

When I run the above lines in command prompt it works fine but when I save it as a batch file and run the file it connects to mysql but doesn't perform the sql scripts.

Comment: xyz here is your db name ?

Comment: Yes xyz is the name of db

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now what I see is wrong here is that while executing the above commands one by one in your prompt, once you run `mysql -u root mysql`, you are in the mysql console. So your `source` command would work there but would not work in your batch since you are not in mysql console while running the batch file.

Solution:
What you can do for this is, instead of using `source` in mysql you can use

```
mysql dbname < filename
```

in your batch file in place of

```
mysql -u root mysql
use xyz;
source C:/Users/abc/Desktop/xyz.sql;
```

[This link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/batch-mode.html) can assist you further if needed

Answer (score 1):

You could write something like this

```
mysql -u dbUsername yourDatabase -e "SELECT * FROM table;"
```

Or to run repeating tasks create a runtasks.bat file, save under the root of your project then write your cmd tasks inside

```
mysql -u dbUser -e "DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS testDatabase;"
mysql -u dbUser -e "CREATE DATABASE testDatabase;"

php index.php migration latest #runs your migration files

cd application\tests
phpunit
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work

```
mysql -u root xyz < C:/Users/abc/Desktop/xyz.sql;
```

It sources the SQL commands from your file

Comment: On running this the cmd exits and nothing happens

Comment: If the database was updated, it ran okay.  No output is expected.

Comment: the script which I am running should create a table in the database

Comment: Could you post the script?  You could also test it by creating a new database and running the same script.

Comment: CREATE TABLE MyGuests10 (
id INT(6) UNSIGNED AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
firstname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
lastname VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
email VARCHAR(50),
reg_date TIMESTAMP
)
This is the script which I am running.

Comment: You need to add a semicolon at the end to let MySQL know where the command ends.

Comment: Added semicolon. Still the same problem

Comment: Is there a password for the root user?

Comment: No password. The script which I posted above when I copy and paste it in command prompt, it works fine

Answer (score 0):

This would work.

```
mysql.exe -u user_name -p -h _host_ _schema_ -e "select 1 from dual;"
```

This will also give you output on same command terminal